# Avoid creation, changes etc. on legacy database tables

Tags: grails, grails-orm, legacy-database

My grails-project contains also tables from a legacy database.
These tables must not be touched in any way by the grails-app.

Even when running in the develop environment the tables must be untouched. 
How can that be done?

Comment: try disabling the dbCreate line in DataSource.groovy

Comment: Sorry, a stupid question. I was thinking that in the first tests in production-environment there is still a good chance that I need to rebuild the tables a few times and as I use a few legacy-tables, just for reading, I can't have the option that re-creates tables unless there where some way to exclude certain tables. But I think I could manage to manually update the new tables when necessary.

Comment: why manually ? save yourself all the hassle look up `schema-export` - you can get grails from development to dump entire db structure into  a DDL.sql  file, If tables already exist. Look through file for segment you need. http://docs.grails.org/2.2.1/ref/Command%20Line/schema-export.html

Comment: That was a good idea, I've never used it before but I'll test it. Thanks.

Comment: I know grails rocks dude :)